# Find the index until which the subvector is unqiue (has no duplicates)

Tags: r, performance, duplicates, unique, rcpp

Given is a vector

`x <- c("A","B","C","A","C","B","C","A")`

Now, for every element x_i in x, I want to find the index until which the vector beginning at x_i has no duplicates and save those indices in a vector (same length as x).

**Example:**

Starting with the first element "A" in x, the solution is 3, since beginning in "A", we have "B","C" and finally "A" on index 4.
Here, at index 4, the subvector consisting of "A","B","C","A" has a duplicate "A", hence the answer is 3.

We continue with the second element "B". We then get the sequence "B","C","A","C" and have a duplicate, namely "C". Hence the answer will be 4. (Its not 3, since "B" is already the second element, hence we have to add 1)

Now, the third element. It is "C" and we get the sequence "C","A","C", which gives a first duplicate. Hence the answer is 4. (We have "C" and "A" as unique length 2 vector, but "C" is already the third element, so we have to add 2).

I hope it is clear what to do.

This question is only for performance-boosting. I already have a working function

```
uniqueTill <- function(x) {
  res <- unlist(lapply(1:length(x), function(i) which(duplicated(x[i:length(x)]))[1]+i-2))
  res[is.na(res)] <- length(x)
  res
}
```

We can now check the function with:

```
inds <- uniqueTill(x)
#check if the vectors are in fact unqiue
lapply(1:length(inds), function(k) x[k:inds[k]])
lapply(1:length(inds), function(k) any(duplicated(x[k:inds[k]])))

#check if the next element in the original vector makes the subvectors no more unique
lapply(1:length(inds), function(k) x[k:(inds[k]+1)])
lapply(1:length(inds), function(k) any(duplicated(x[k:(inds[k]+1)]))) #here the last 3 are FALSE since there are no more duplicates, but thats wanted
```

I already got a small performance increase with the following function:
(This function does not give the desired output, because of the behaviour of which.min on vectors only containing FALSE, which comes into game when we are reaching the end of the vector where no more duplicates occur. Maybe you also have an idea how to fix this little problem)

```
uniqueTill2 <- function(x) {
  res <- unlist(lapply(1:length(x), function(i) which.min(!duplicated(x[i:length(x)]))+i-2))
  res[is.na(res)] <- length(x)
  res
}

#newer version
uniqueTill2 <- function(x) {
  unlist(lapply(1:length(x), function(i) {
    dups <- duplicated(x[i:length(x)])
    if(!any(dups)) return(length(x))
    which.max(dups)+i-2
  }))
}
```

Instead of taking "which" in every iteration and then taking its first index, its enough to get the first min.index via "which.min".
Therefore we need to negate the duplicated vector, such that a duplicated element giving TRUE (=1 in numeric) becomes a FALSE (=0 in numeric) such that the use of "which.min" works.

I got the following benchmarks:

```
x <- c("A","B","C","A","C","B","C","A")
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(uniqueTill(x),uniqueTill2(x))
Unit: microseconds
           expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
  uniqueTill(x) 63.002 66.5010 74.50998 68.4015 73.3005 200.300   100
 uniqueTill2(x) 56.401 58.8505 63.29607 60.8505 63.4510 119.901   100

xx <- rep(x,1e3)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(uniqueTill(xx),uniqueTill2(xx),times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  uniqueTill(xx) 752.8640 761.6679 822.4813 845.1330 850.2489 906.9668    10
 uniqueTill2(xx) 719.3167 725.2254 744.7558 727.9224 747.4992 812.6559    10
```

Do you have any ideas how to speed things up? Some Rcpp would also be very nice.

Comment: `uniqueTill` and `uniqueTill2` do not output the same result.

Comment: Ahh, right. Which.min gives always a result, also where the "which" return empty vectors (resulting in the NAs I have to fill). Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `which.min(!duplicated)` an equivalent is `which.max(duplicated)` saving a vector negation operation.